# Difference between references of Linux "utilities", "commands" and "programs"

Tags: command-line, utilities, terminology

I read uses of the word "utilities" for commands/programs such as 'ls', 'chmod', 'mv', etc.

Is "commands" is Linux referring to the same things as `top`, `ps`, etc., or are those something different? What about "programs"? Are those the ones that don't come with the standard distribution which need to be installed like `irssi`, `emacs`, `kismet`, etc.?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This question is hard to answer, as there is no formal definitions of those terms and different people will use them differently. I here only give my use of them, others will have different points if view.

For me tool and utility are synonyms. I use the words for small programs which just do one small job. I'd call e.g. all applications implemented as applets in [busybox](http://www.busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html) tools or utility.

Any application is a program for me. I.e. 'ls' is a tool, a utility and a program. Firefox is a program but I wouldn't call it neither tool nor utility.

Comment: A `/usr/bin/compose` by any other name would still point to the same i-node.

Comment: Are you sure that you commented on the right answer? Because even after reading thrice, I still can't figure how that relates to my answer...

Comment: A reference to a concept put to paper by Shakespeare regarding categorizations. It was marred by the fact that nothing in computing smells much and by the limited matches for `{/usr,}/*bin/*se`. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_rose_by_any_other_name_would_smell_as_sweet